# Is there any way to show checkboxes in VBA using Loop?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to show checkboxes  according to country list.
When User will check several countries and press submit, the specific countries will be added in report.
Here is the code I am trying

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
total_countries = namerange.Cells(namerange.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To total_countries
UserForm1.checkox(i).Visible = True
UserForm1.checkox(i).Caption = namerange.Cells(i, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

Please help in this issue.

Comment: "checkox"? Use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @SJR `Option Explicit` wouldn't catch this if it's a typo, but it'd be a compile error.

Comment: Oh right. Well use OE anyway @OP.

Comment: "Here is the code I am trying" - when posting code it helpful to explain *what specific problem* you're having when you try to run it.  Otherwise we're just guessing what the issue might be...  Are you getting an error message?  If Yes then what is the message and which line triggers it?  Does it instead do osmething unexpected?  If Yes then what?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your **core** question

> *Is there any way to show checkboxes in VBA using Loop?*

You can reference *checkbox* controls via the `Controls` collection
(generally comprising *all* referred controls) by isolating
them via a `TypeName` check

- in a `For Each` loop

```
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
            Debug.Print ctrl.Name, ctrl.Caption
        'execute further actions ...
        End If
    Next
```

- in a `For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1` loop

```
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
        If TypeName(Me.Controls(i)) = "CheckBox" Then
            Debug.Print i, Me.Controls(i).Name, Me.Controls(i).Caption, Me.Controls(i).Visible
            'execute further actions ... 
       End If
    Next
```

Assuming you have enumerated all checkbox names in a consistant way
(e.g. `Country1`, `Country2`, ...) you might procede
*without* extra check as follows:

```
     Dim i As Long
     For i = 1 To total_countries
         Debug.Print i, Me.Controls("Country" & i).Name, Me.Controls("Country" & i).Caption
         'execute further actions ...
     Next
```

This should give you a start; it should be easy to include the following propositions in further code:

**Further hints:**

- Always use `Option Explicit` in the declaration head of your code modules.
- Use the `Me.` particle within the Userform code module,
  don't refer to the default object as there might be other userform instances
- If you have a given number of checkboxes, it won't suffice to make them visible,
  you will need to set visibility for the rest to `False`
- Doing so will also make it necessary to redefine at least some `.Top` positions.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @T.M.'s answer. *Do not* use string comparisons since it's error-prone (as in the case with `TypeName`) because you can misspell. Use `TypeOf` operator instead:

```vb
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        MsgBox ctrl.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Appreciated addition +:) @JohnyL

Comment: @T.M. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a completely different solution?

Don't use a userform - instead: show the countries on a worksheet and let the user select the countries by making an x.

Use the new FILTER-function to retrieve the selected countries in a new range: `=FILTER(tblCountrySelection[Country], tblCountrySelection[selected]<>"","[nothing selected]")`

Create a name for the cell with the FILTER formula.

And use this name/range in your VBA code or whereever you need it.

[image]

You can enhance the "form" by adding a selection-change-event to the worksheet.
When the user clicks on a cell in "selected"-column the value switches from x to empty and back:

```vb
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cSelected As Range
Set cSelected = Target.Cells(1, 1) 'in case multiple cells are selected only handle the first one

'if the selected cell crosses selected-column of tblCountrySelection run checkUncheckCell on selected cell
If Not Intersect(cSelected, loCountries.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
    checkUncheckCell cSelected
End If

End Sub



Private Sub checkUncheckCell(c As Range)

If c.Value = "" Then
    c.Value = "x"
Else
    c.Value = ""
End If

End Sub



Public Property Get loCountries() As ListObject

Set loCountries = Me.ListObjects("tblCountrySelection")

End Property
```